# How can I execute a method with type <T> against an iteration of types?

Tags: c#, loops, reflection, types, default

Sorry for the odd question wording.. I understand the concept but my google skills are lacking today.

I have a method that allows me to specify a generic to use for its work.  Any class that gets passed in will inherit a class of "BaseProduct".  This allows me to write code like the following.

```
SyncProductsByType<PublicationProduct>();
SyncProductsByType<ApparelProduct>();
.... etc
```

I just want to do a foreach on the basetype's subclasses, but I can't get the syntax right.
So far, I have:

```
Type parentType = typeof(BaseProduct);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
IEnumerable<Type> subclasses = types.Where(t => t.BaseType == parentType);
```

but thats ALL WRONG for use in a foreach. I can't figure out how to do this sort of thing:

```
foreach (<T> subclasse yadda yadda) {
    SyncProductsByType<something?>();
}
```

Thats not even close.  Thanks

Edit:
I don't believe this is a duplicate because there is an assumption that I'm trying to Invoke a method in all classes of type .  No, what I'm trying to do is call a method against all derives types against a single method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: How do i use that answer? I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: @CarComp as the answer says, you need to get the `MethodInfo` for your type -- `var methodInfo = typeof(EnclosingType).GetMethod("SyncProductsByType")`. Then you can call it with each member of `subclasses`: `methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(subclass).Invoke(...)`

Comment: See edit.  I'm trying to be more clear what I'm asking

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhh....Marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all descendant classes and then invoke the generic method this way:

```
class Program
{
    class BaseClass
    {
        public static void Generic<T>() where T : BaseClass
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
        }
    }
    class FirstClass : BaseClass
    {

    }
    class SecondClass : BaseClass
    {

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(BaseClass).GetMethod("Generic");

        foreach (var item in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                        .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass))))
        {
            MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(item);
            generic.Invoke(null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
A little optimalization.

Comment: Take the call to `typeof(BaseClass).GetMethod("Generic")` out of the loop. It's relatively expensive, and doesn't need to be repeated for each `item`.

Comment: @canton7 Yeah you are right, reflection isn't the fastest. I corrected it for the sake of accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void SyncProductsByType<T>() where T : BaseProduct
    {
        // this method is a simple wrapper with constraint

        SyncProductsByType(typeof(T));
    }

    public static void SyncProductsByType(Type type)
    {
        // decide whether this should public, private or internal

        if (type.BaseType != typeof(BaseProduct))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(type));

        // do work
    }
}

public abstract class BaseProduct
{
}

public class ApparelProduct : BaseProduct
{
}
```

Comment: I don't see where that will call `SyncProductsByType` against all derived types of `BaseProduct`.  Additionally, I already have the static method `SyncProductsByType<T>` written. I don't know how to iterate all derived baseproduct types against it.  Thanks though

Comment: The definition `SyncProductsByType(Type)` allows you to call such method in your `foreach` loop.

Comment: It is a duplicate.  Sorry all.  Brain isn't working this morning.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [Type.IsSubclassOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.issubclassof?view=netframework-4.8) this check if a type is a subclass of another type. The only way to invoke a method with said `Type` object is by getting a generic definition `MethodInfo` and then using `MakeGenericMethod` to create a generic method which has `T` set to the specified `Type`, for example:

```
Type parentType = typeof(BaseProduct);

Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

var genericDefinition = typeof(BaseClass).GetMethod("SyncProductsByType");

foreach (Type type in types)
{
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(parentType))
    {
        genericDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(instance, null);
    }
}
```